# using HtmlAgility pack in a Windows Store app

Tags: c#, xpath, windows-store-apps, html-agility-pack

In my Windows Store app, I've got the following piece of code to extract a div with the id=pos_0

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(my_html_string);

var div_i_need = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("id") && x.Attributes["id"].Value == "pos_0").FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there an easier way to do this? `SelectSingleNode` doesn't exist in this version of the library, and `Descendants` doesn't seem to accept XPath

Comment: You can replace `Where` with `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack can't perform XPath query since .NET doesn't have XPath implementation for Windows Store. Your code can be simplified a bit by using `GetAttributeValue()` method and strip out `Where()`  :

```
var div_i_need = doc.DocumentNode
                    .Descendants("div")
                    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetAttributeValue("id", "") == "pos_0");
```

`GetAttributeValue()` returns the second parameter if the attribute is not found

Comment: Seems like a good answer. Not the one I *want*  - a bit annoying that there's no xpath implementation - but what can you do!